# WPF C# Get selected row item Listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, data-binding

I have a popup ListView, declared in this way:

```
<ListView x:Name="ShowFileLV" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}" 
          DataContext="{Binding}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedEmployee}" 
          SelectionMode="Single">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClick"   
                                      Tag="Name" 
                                      Content="Name" />
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="140" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Click="SortClick"
                                      Tag="ID" 
                                      Content="ID" />
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

The list and the sorting work fine. My problem is that I would like to get the SelectedEmployee directly updated when I select a row (not sure if ListViewItem is the right choice) or even better, to get only the ID or the Name:

```
public ListViewItem SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedEmployee= value;           
    }
}
```

This was working until I used a ListBox (instead of the ListView) loaded with a List of Strings, each string containing both Name and ID, like this one

```
<ListBox Name="ShowFileLV" 
         SelectionMode="Single" 
         SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Employee}" 
         Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListPopupItems}" >
</ListBox>
```

Using a public string like:

```
public String Employee
{
    get
    {
        return _employee;
    }
    set
    {
        _employee= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Employee");
    }
}
```

When I selected a row it automatically set the public string Employee, without need of code. 
How can I do his using the ListView and Collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SelectedItem binding will set the value to the type in your collection EmployeeCollection. So assuming that EmployeeCollection is an `ObservableCollection<Employee>`, you need to change the SelectedEmployee from a ListViewItem to Employee. Also, make sure you are using the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface.

```
public Employee SelectedEmployee
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedEmployee;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedEmployee= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
    }
}
```

If you want only the Name or ID, then use SelectedValue and SelectedValuePath instead of SelectedItem.

```
<ListView x:Name="ShowFileLV" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection}" 
          DataContext="{Binding}" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedEmployee}"
          SelectedValuePath="Name"
          SelectionMode="Single"> 

public string SelectedEmployee
{
    get { return _selectedEmployee; }
    set
    {
       _selectedEmployee = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedEmployee");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply Lee. I am not using INotifyPropertyChanged and actually I don't know how to use it. But I can add that when I run the code I get {MySolutionName.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel.Employee} as "value" in the set property of SelectedEmployee. Why I get an address instead of the row content?

Comment: You must have missed the SelectedValuePath. This should be the property you want such as Name or ID (if ID is an int then change SelectedEmployee to an int). It works without SelectedValuePath when you collection is a bunch of strings but when its a class, you need to tell it which property to use.